# Strange GetTickCount Issue

Tags: c++, windows, time, unix-timestamp

I am building a simple console c++ application . When I am running it on one machine which is **Windows XP i get output . Which looks fine .**

> TickTime: 134993550
>
> TickTime: 134993560

When I run same it on another machine which is **Windows Server 2008 R2** I get following output and I dont understand how it can be ?

> TickTime: 654336178
>
> TickTime: 654336194

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    while(i<100000){
        cout << " TickTime :" << GetTickCount();
        i++;
    }
  
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about the numbers themselves? It returns the number of milliseconds since the computer started.

Comment: Could you explain what it is that you find puzzling about the second example?

Comment: @NPE My bad . I thought its gonna give me unix timestamp. What function can I use to get a unix timestamp/epoch time .

Comment: @SoneshDabhi, `std::chrono::<insert clock here>::now()` will give you the time since epoch.

Comment: @SoneshDabhi: Learn to use google, it will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrieves the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since the system was started, up to 49.7 days.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

> What function can I use to get a unix timestamp/epoch time

For this, you can use `time()` et al:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f4c8f33.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the issue. GetTickCount() returns the time since system start, nothing absolute. In either case the difference is a few ticks (10, resp. 16), so it looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the asker of this question is confused that the XP machine seems to be executing the code faster than the server machine.  The answer to that puzzle is complex, with many variables, but to name the two biggest:  hardware resource differences and work-load differences (what else is running on the two).  Also, if you let it run for a while and were to load other programs etc... I think you would find that those "tics" would not stay static...

Simply put, the server presumably may have better hardware, but if it's running a bunch of software that can affect it.

Answer (score 0):

So, you probably want 
[GetSystemTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms724390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)